# Calibrating AutoML models in H2O

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o

From what I can see in the [docs](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/calibrate_model.html), H2O supports calibration for GBM, DRF, XGBoost models only and has to be specified prior to the training phase.

I find it confusing. If calibration is a post-processing step and is model agnostic, shouldn't it be possible to calibrate any model trained using H2O, even after the training process is finished?

Currently, I'm dealing with a model that I've trained using [AutoML](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html). Even though it is a GBM model, I'm not able to easily calibrate it by providing a `calibrate_model` parameter as it is not supported by AutoML. I don't see any option to calibrate it after it's trained either.

Does anyone know an easy way to calibrate already-trained H2O models? Is it necessary to "manually" calibrate them using algorithms such as Platt scaling or is there a way to do it without using any extra libraries?
Thanks

Comment: FYI: I added a link to a Jira ticket for this feature request to Michal's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

> I find it confusing. If calibration is a post-processing step

The reason why it is part of model training right now is to have it in MOJO (our deployment artifact).

> and is model agnostic, shouldn't it be possible to calibrate any model trained using H2O, even after the training process is finished?

Calibrating a model ex-post makes a lot of sense, all the code is already in - it “just” needs to be exposed to users.  We created a ticket for this [here](https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-8160).